# Chromium theme changed automatically

Tags: 14.04, themes, chromium

I was just trying random experiment in terminal after typing `indicator-netspeed &`.

I just typed `stop` and instantly terminal got closed (acceptable) and theme of chromium changed (unacceptable).

Now, how to make the theme normal?

[image]

I have tried to reset browser setting but did not helped!

Comment: Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: @amanthethy Yup and that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the Chromium settings you should be able to change the theme back in there, when I was messing around with a beta NVIDIA driver it changed Google Chrome back to the blue theme and all I had to do was go and change it back in the settings.